# tty7 Server Crash (logs included with problem, unknown solution)

Tags: networking, network-manager, suspend, vnc

I currently run an Ubuntu 21.04 sever. Recently, I installed VNC on the server. I VNC onto the server by ssh tunneling by running `ssh -L 5901:localhost:5900 username@ip -i ~/.ssh/privatekey`, then use tigerVNC to connect to localhost port 5901. Nothing intensive runs on the server, except 3 nodejs projects.

My Issue: After 5 hours of ending the VNC session, the server crashes. When running `last -x`, The Following Errors Come For crash:

```
tanish   tty7         :0               Fri May 14 06:05 - crash  (09:41)
tanish   tty7         :0               Fri May 14 23:38 - crash  (01:08)
mihir    tty7         :0               Sat May 15 01:06 - crash  (01:17)
tanish   pts/0        (My Public IP)    Sat May 15 01:05 - crash  (01:18)
tanish   tty7         :0               Sat May 15 22:39 - crash  (05:19)
```

:0 is the display I use for VNC and tty7 has something to do with a VNC terminal.

When I Checked Syslogs (, Right before the crash, I got this for 4/5 of the crashes, the 4th crash being the exception.

```
May 14 06:17:01 (myservername) CRON[2046]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May 14 06:19:53 (myservername) systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
May 14 06:19:53 (myservername) systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service: Succeeded.
May 14 06:19:53 (myservername) systemd[1]: Finished Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
May 14 06:25:02 (myservername) CRON[2065]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily ))
May 14 06:26:11 (myservername) NetworkManager[745]: <info>  [1620973571.6512] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
May 14 06:26:11 (myservername) NetworkManager[745]: <info>  [1620973571.6516] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
May 14 06:26:11 (myservername) ModemManager[776]: <info>  [sleep-monitor] system is about to suspend
May 14 06:26:11 (myservername) systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
May 14 06:26:11 (myservername) systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
May 14 06:26:11 (myservername) kernel: [ 1304.854501] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
May 14 06:26:11 (myservername) systemd-sleep[2068]: Suspending system...
Random @^@^@^s for like 12 lines
May 14 15:47:39 (myservername) kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 5.11.0-17-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-002) (gcc (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1) 10.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.36.1) #18-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 6 20:10:11 UTC 2021 (Ubuntu 5.11.0-17.18-generic 5.11.12)
```

If anyone knows how to fix this **for ubuntu 21.04**, I would appreciate ANY help. The node projects that run are very time sensitive, and a downtime of 4 hours, means angry clients! Thanks in advance!

Edit: Running `sudo systemd-inhibit` returns:

```
WHO                          UID USER    PID  COMM            WHAT              WHY                                                       MODE
ModemManager                 0   root    787  ModemManager    sleep             ModemManager needs to reset devices                       delay
NetworkManager               0   root    707  NetworkManager  sleep             NetworkManager needs to turn off networks                 delay
UPower                       0   root    1310 upowerd         sleep             Pause device polling                                      delay
Unattended Upgrades Shutdown 0   root    824  unattended-upgr shutdown          Stop ongoing upgrades or perform upgrades before shutdown delay
lightdm                      113 lightdm 1262 unity-settings- handle-lid-switch Multiple displays attached                                block
lightdm                      113 lightdm 1212 unity-greeter   handle-power-key  Unity Greeter handling keypresses                         block
lightdm                      113 lightdm 1262 unity-settings- sleep             GNOME needs to lock the screen                            delay

7 inhibitors listed.
```

This also confirms the syslogs showing that Network manager was shutting down the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the logs:

```
tanish   tty7         :0               Fri May 14 06:05 - crash  (09:41)
```

reads as 06:05 start time + 09:41 runtime = 15:46 crash time, which allowing for rounding error matches the reboot time:

```
May 14 06:26:11 (myservername) systemd-sleep[2068]: Suspending system...
Random @^@^@^s for like 12 lines
May 14 15:47:39 (myservername) kernel: [    0.000000]...
```

The "crash" was because the server was rebooted during sleep.  Your real problem was that sleep after 20 minutes, which was not a crash, but seemed like it.

Network manager was only *delaying* a shutdown request from something else.  I suspect it's caused by a sleep on idle power management setting.  Idle is a misleading name for user not at keyboard.

If you cannot fix that, a workaround is to run any program on the server which needs to keep running unattended with:

```
systemd-inhibit COMMAND
```

to block sleep and shutdown requests until it has completed.